# Object oriented why isn't this grading method working?

Tags: java

I want to know if I removed my second if where if the points is higher than 100 print enter a lower grading point this is not working ,but when i type in -100 it works why so?

```
public class nameofclass {

    private int grade;

    public void enterGrade(int points) {

        if(points > 0) {
            grade = grade + points;
        } else {
            if(points > 100) { 
                System.out.println("Enter a lower grading point");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter positive grading point");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: points > 0 is true for points > 100 so that else branch never executes.

Comment: @AlexK. I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler (or JIT) completely ignored that unreachable code.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What have you tried to do to solve this yourself?

Comment: Just because you use Java you probably shouldn't tag this simple program "object-oriented-analysis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `if` filters *points* more than 0, which means the **JVM only goes to  `else` when the *points* are less than or equal to 0**. So your second `if` never gets executed.

```
if(points > 0) {
    ...
} else {
    //only if points are less than or equal 0

    if(points > 100) {
        //never runs
    }
}
```

So put your second `if` inside the first `if` like this,

```
if(points > 0) {
    if(points > 100) {
        System.out.println("Enter a lower grading point");
    }
} else {
    //only if points are less than or equal 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code:

```
Points : 120
```

In first if statement is always true because (points > 100)
So it doesn't goes to else part.

```
Points: -100
```

First if statement is false then it goes to else part.
Then :     if(points > 100)   statement is false.  And print the value  : Enter positive grading point